# Unpacking Data Frame of Tuples and performing operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I am trying to unpack a dataframe of Tuples and perform simple operations within the tuples.

The Data Frame looks like

('10','20','50'), ('50','11','23'), ('None'), ('24', '13', '43')

('24', '34', '12'), ('90', '34', '15'), ('34', '16', '76'), ('None')

It's a n*m data frame and what I want to do is add the first two values inside of each tuple and divide by the third when the numeric values actually appear.

Comment: If you have code, try posting it here. Also, if you have the `dataframe`. `print` the dataframe to console and post the result. It will be formatted in a nicer way

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question correctly. This is what you are trying to do?

```
>>> df
              0             1             2             3
0  [10, 20, 50]  [50, 11, 23]          None  [24, 13, 43]
1  [24, 34, 12]  [90, 34, 15]  [34, 16, 76]          None
>>> def add_divide(row):
...     return [((tup[0]+tup[1])/tup[2]) if tup else None for tup in row]
... 
>>> df.apply(add_divide, axis=1)
          0         1         2         3
0  0.600000  2.652174       NaN  0.860465
1  4.833333  8.266667  0.657895       NaN
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is the documentation for the `apply` function